# When are questions tweeted?

Tags: support, site-promotion

I sometimes notice that questions are promoted on [twitter.com](http://twitter.com/StackSciFi), which is shown in the respective edit log.

I was wondering what inner logic this follows. Is this done by our beloved StackExchange crew on a whim or automatically/randomly by some bot? It doesn't appear to be tied to vote score.

Bonus question: Are posts promoted on other social/blogging/whatever networks?

Comment: I'm curious about this as well.  I wouldn't mind knowing the answer to this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each Stack Exchange site has an associated Twitter account that is set up by the company when the site's public beta begins. These all follow the naming convention @Stack[topic] - more or less. So, to answer your question, the [@StackSciFi](http://twitter.com/stackscifi) account was created by the company, and it, like almost all of our Twitter accounts, tweets content that is determined by an algorithm. I believe the most recent version (as [explained by Jeff Atwood on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101340/166017)) is:

> - per-site blog posts (if present)
> - chat events, if started by a moderator
> - interesting questions on the site
>
> Every three hours (on average).

And also:

> - bountied questions
> - interesting answers of +3 or better
> - unanswered questions of +3 or better
> - particularly hot meta questions (not support or bug though)

About every two hours.

Anything that has a mention in the edit log of being promoted via Twitter has been tweeted by one of our bots.

In addition to the [per-site twitter accounts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/), there is also an account for the whole network: [@StackExchange](http://twitter.com/stackexchange). This is also managed by an algorithm that has it tweet out interesting questions from around the network, similar to the way [stackexchange.com/questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions) works.

On a slightly different note, there are a handful of accounts that are run by the SE team. The [@StackHQ](http://twitter.com/stackhq) twitter account is sometimes used to share questions and answers, though we tend to use it more for office antics, contests we're running, or other fun news.

There are also Stack Exchange [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/stackexchange) and [Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/101120115153580954446/posts) pages that promote content and news from around the network. These are both run by humans, not bots. If you have Scifi & Fantasy posts that you think are especially worthy of promotion to a wider audience, [you can submit them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125293/can-beta-mods-suggest-questions-to-be-advertised-cross-network/125405#125405) and we'll try to post them.

Comment: Thanks, that was quite informative!

Comment: How does the bot define "interesting"?

Comment: @Martha I believe it uses the "active" tab of the "questions" page.